# detecting event capture support javascript

Tags: javascript, modernizr

Is there a way to detect if a browser supports event capturing as well as event bubbling? I have checked http://modernizr.com/ but can't see any information in the documentation.

Am I correct in thinking that IE < 9 doesn't support event capture but in other browsers it should be ok?

For clarity I want to detect if the browser supports the event capture phase of the event DOM model as well as the event bubble phase.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "event capturing"? Every browser since 1998 supports *some* events.

Comment: @Pekka웃 - I assume he means the capture phase of the DOM event model (as oppose to the bubble phase, which is where you would most often listen for the event).

Comment: yes I meant the event capture phase over the event bubble phase

Answer (score 1):

There may be better approaches to this, but this is the first thing I came up with. You would need to create an element, bind an event handler to it in capture phase, fire an event on it, and check the `eventPhase` property in the event handler:

```
var button = document.getElementById("example");

document.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    console.log(e.eventPhase); // 1 === capture, 2 === target, 3 === bubble
}, true);

evt.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
button.dispatchEvent(evt);
```

You would probably want to add in all sorts of other checks (e.g. for `dispatchEvent` support) and you'd need to actually create the `button` element in the code (and insert it into the DOM, hidden).

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jamesallardice/VRbfw/2/) containing the above code to get you started.

Comment: [docs for `event.eventPhase`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.eventPhase), for reference